# Change the size of UISlider thumb in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I am new to Swift. I have a `UISlider` and I want to make the size of the **thumb of UISlider** to smaller.

I tried to set a smaller image using code :

```
self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "progress_thumb"), forState: .Normal)
```

But it stretches the image.

Is it because of the image I have? How can I implement `thumbRectForBounds` here?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it solved now.It was because of the image size.When I make the image into to even smaller size, it correctly showed in the UISlider in the exact size I wanted.

Comment: What size you have given? @Neethu

Comment: Can i resize the thumb without giving the image of Thumb?